# How to make my application paid in android market?

Tags: android, google-play

I have 10 videos in my application.I want to make it 3 videos as free and remaining 7 videos as paid.How can i handle it programatically.If any one have idea help me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make use of managed purchases on Google Play.  Each one of the seven paid videos can be given a separate SKU (or in any combination you desire), and you can charge the user using in-app-purchases to unlock the videos.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Comment: I am place 10 vedio in gallery first three free and remaining are paid.if these is possible to make it programatically

Comment: The way to make this happen is by using in-app-purchases to allow the user to pay to unlock the paid videos.